# tcolorbox documentation: documenting dynamic keypaths

Tags: tcolorbox, pgfkeys, package-writing, documentation

I'm documenting a package that has certain key paths which are created dynamically (either by some command or on the fly via the pgfkeys `.unknown` handler).

I want to document these keys with the `docKey` environment from tcolorbox, but the first arguments (both the optional and the mandatory) do not work with macros such as `\meta{}`.

Is there a proper way of doing this?

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{documentation}

\begin{document}

\begin{docKey}
    [mypackage/keypath]
    {my key}
    {=value}
    {}
    The \texttt{keypath} part of the key path is dynamic. Using \meta{keypath} breaks.

    Putting both in the mandatory argument as \verb|{\meta{keypath}/my key}| also breaks.
    
    What is the best alternative?
\end{docKey}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the detailed answers, @Marijn & @mushimushiZ! I am studying them for ideas and techniques.

As for this specific problem, it turns out that it is possible to do with the options provided by tcolorbox itself, via the `doc label` key, *if* the macros are kept to the key itself (and not in the optional path argument):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{documentation}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\begin{docKey}
    [mypackage]
    [doc label=keypath/mykey]
    {\meta{keypath}/my key}
    {=value}
    {}
    The \texttt{keypath} part of the key path is dynamic and corresponds to ...
\end{docKey}

Can be referenced: \refKey{/mypackage/keypath/mykey}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image: document]

[image: index]

Answer (score 7):

`tcolorbox` assumes the value of first optional argument of `docKey` environment (also the value of key `/tcb/doc keypath`) is fully expandable and uses it in printing, label name, and index name. Since `\meta{...}` is not fully expandable, errors are raised.

In the following example, I split the role of `doc keypath` into four:

- printed key name
- label name, can be set by `doc keypath label`
- printed index name, can be set by `doc keypath index`
- sorted index name, can be set by `doc keypath sort index`.

Modified `doc keypath` will set all four of them, and a new key `doc formatted keypath` sets both the first and the third.

Usage:

```tex
\begin{docKey}
    [keypath][doc formatted keypath=\meta{keypath}]
    {my key}
    {=value}
    {}
\end{docKey}

See \refKey{/keypath/my key}.
```

Full example:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{documentation}
\makeindex

\makeatletter
\newif\iftcb@doc@formatted@keypath

\tcbset{
  doc keypath/.style={%
    doc@keypath={#1},
    doc keypath label={#1},
    doc keypath index={#1},doc keypath sort index={#1},
  },
  doc@keypath/.store in=\kvtcb@doc@keypath,
  doc formatted keypath/.code=%
    \tcb@doc@formatted@keypathtrue
    \pgfkeysalso{doc@keypath=#1,doc keypath index=#1},
%  doc keypath name/.store in=\kvtcb@doc@keypath,
  doc keypath label/.store in=\kvtcb@doc@keypath@label,
  doc keypath index/.store in=\kvtcb@doc@keypath@index,
  doc keypath sort index/.store in=\kvtcb@doc@keypath@sortindex,
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_nopar:Npn \__tcobox_print_key:
  {
    \textcolor{\kvtcb@col@key}{\tcb@doc@bfseries\ttfamily
    \tl_if_empty:NF \kvtcb@doc@keypath
      {
        \iftcb@doc@formatted@keypath
          /\kvtcb@doc@keypath/
        \else
          /\__tcobox_sanitize_tl:V\kvtcb@doc@keypath/
        \fi
      }
    \__tcobox_sanitize_tl:V\kvtcb@doc@name}
  }

\cs_set_nopar:Npn \__tcobox_index_key:
  {
    \iftcb@doc@toindex
      \kvtcb@index@command{\kvtcb@doc@sortindex\idx@actual\tcbIndexPrintKeyCA{\kvtcb@doc@index}}
      \tl_if_empty:NTF \kvtcb@doc@keypath@index
        {
          \kvtcb@index@command{\kvtcb@text@keys\idx@level\kvtcb@doc@sortindex\idx@actual\tcbIndexPrintKeyC{\kvtcb@doc@index}}
        }
        {
          \kvtcb@index@command{\kvtcb@text@keys\idx@level\kvtcb@doc@keypath@sortindex\idx@actual\tcbIndexPrintKeyC{/\kvtcb@doc@keypath@index/}
            \idx@level\kvtcb@doc@sortindex\idx@actual\tcbIndexPrintKeyC{\kvtcb@doc@index}}
        }
    \fi
  }

\cs_set:Npn \__tcobox_doc_head_key:
  {
    \__tcobox_print_key:
    \__tcobox_index_key:
    \tl_if_empty:NTF \kvtcb@doc@keypath@label
      {
        \seq_if_in:NVF \g__tcobox_label_seq \kvtcb@doc@label
          {
            \protected@edef\@currentlabel{\kvtcb@doc@name}
            \label{key:\kvtcb@doc@label}
            \seq_gput_left:NV \g__tcobox_label_seq \kvtcb@doc@label
          }
      }
      {
        \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl {/\kvtcb@doc@keypath@label/\kvtcb@doc@label}
        \seq_if_in:NVF \g__tcobox_label_seq \l_tmpa_tl
          {
            \protected@edef\@currentlabel{/\kvtcb@doc@keypath/\kvtcb@doc@name}
            \label{key:/\kvtcb@doc@keypath@label/\kvtcb@doc@label}
            \seq_gput_left:NV \g__tcobox_label_seq \l_tmpa_tl
          }
      }
    {\ttfamily\kvtcb@doc@parameter}
    \tcb@doc@do@description
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{docKey}
    [keypath][doc formatted keypath=\meta{keypath}]
    {my key}
    {=value}
    {}
    The \texttt{keypath} part of the key path is dynamic. Using \meta{keypath} breaks.

    Putting both in the mandatory argument as \verb|{\meta{keypath}/my key}| also breaks.
    
    What is the best alternative?
\end{docKey}

See \refKey{/keypath/my key}.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that both the optional and the mandatory argument are used to create a label for referencing with `\refKey`, i.e., `\refKey{/mypackage/keypath/my key}`. In the value of a label commands such as `\meta` are not allowed.

You can modify the definition of `docKey` slightly to circumvent the issue, by defining the label to be just the name without the optional prefix. One way of doing that is to copy the definition from the `tcolorbox` source and use `\RenewDocumentEnvironment` to make the changes.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{documentation}
\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{docKey}{ O{} +O{} m m +m }{\tcbset{#2,doc description={#5}}%
  \begin{tcb@manual@entry}%
  \begin{tcb@doc@head}{doc@head@key}%
  \ifblank{#1}{%
    \tcb@Print@Key{#3}\tcb@index@Key{#3}\protected@edef\@currentlabel{#3}\label{key:#3}{\ttfamily #4}%
  }{%
    \tcb@Print@Key{/#1/#3}%
    % CHANGE OF LABEL IN FOLLOWING LINE %
    \tcb@index@KeyPath{#1}{#3}\protected@edef\@currentlabel{/#1/#3}\label{key:#3}{\ttfamily #4}%
  }%
  \tcb@doc@do@description%
  \end{tcb@doc@head}\nobreak\tcbset{before upper=}\kvtcb@doc@body@key@before\ignorespaces}%
  {\ifvmode\else\unskip\fi\kvtcb@doc@body@key@after\end{tcb@manual@entry}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{docKey}
    [mypackage/\meta{keypath}]
    {my key}
    {=value}
    {}
    The \texttt{keypath} part of the key path is dynamic. Using \meta{keypath} breaks.

    Putting both in the mandatory argument as \verb|{\meta{keypath}/my key}| also breaks.
    
    What is the best alternative?
\end{docKey}

See \refKey{my key}.

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Remark: maybe `\textit{<keypath>}` is nicer than `\meta{keypath}`:

[image]

Comment: Running your example, I get error undefined control sequence `\tcb@Print@Key` with `tcolorbox` v4.40.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ that could indeed be a version problem, I have v4.12. However, probably a very similar approach could be implemented for a newer version, by copying the actual `\NewDocumentEnvironment` definition from the source of the newer version and changing the label argument (I did not test that theory though, maybe other issues will appear when that is tried).